# The operation "dilation" on the Heisenberg group?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I would like to know why "dilation" on the 3-dimensional Heisenberg group $H^3$ is given by the following operation

$\begin{align}
\varphi_{\lambda} : & \qquad H^3 \longrightarrow H^3\\
 &(x,y,t)\to \varphi_{\lambda} (x,y,t)= (\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda^2 t) 
\end{align}\qquad\mbox{for}\, \lambda\geq0.$

Where the Heisenberg group $H^3$ is the set $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R$ endowed with the group law
$$(x,x,t)\bullet(x',y',t') =\left (x+x',y+y',t+t'+\frac{1}{2}(x y'-x' y)\right).$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: What definition are you using for the Heisenberg group?

Comment: @ Cameron Williams,  see above.

Comment: Cool that's what I thought. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: By definition, the dilation is the automorphism induced by $\phi_{\lambda}$,  multiplying Carnot distances by $\lambda$, see [here](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~pansu/oxford13nov10_beamer.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess: it plays well with the group operation on $\mathbb{H}^3$. Notice that there are quadratic terms in the third component for the group operation. The Heisenberg group is kind of a warping of the usual group structure on $\Bbb R^3-$which is just vector addition of course. If you dilate a sum, it should be the sum of the dilations. We would want the same here since we are just warping the usual structure on $\Bbb R^3$, that is

$$\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}((x,y,t)\cdot(x',y',t')) = \mathcal{D}_{\lambda}(x,y,t)\cdot\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}(x',y',t').$$

Written out slightly,

$$\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}\left(x+x',y+y',t+t' + \frac{1}{2}\left(xy'-x'y\right)\right) = \mathcal{D}_{\lambda}(x,y,t)\cdot\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}(x',y',t').$$

Notice the appearance of *quadratic* terms $xy'$ and $x'y$ in the third component of the group law. If you dilate the $x$, $y$ linearly (which you might as well, or change variables to make the dilation linear), you have to dilate the $t$ quadratically in order for this equation to hold.

In algebraic terms, it's a specific kind of automorphism.

Comment: @ Cameron Williams,  I am not trying to prove that $\varphi$ is a dilation on $H^3$. My problem is that, why the dilation on $H^3$ has for expression $\varphi_{\lambda} (x,y,t)= (\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda^2 t) $.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm explaining. It is quadratic in the last variable so that it plays nicely with the group structure. If you had terms like $x^2y$ in the third coordinate of the group law, then you might need for the dilation to be cubic in the last variable.

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: @ Cameron Williams, this operation of "dilation" is unique ?

Comment: In what sense do you mean?

Comment: In the general sense, the operation of dilation on a Lie group is unique ?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure to be honest. Might warrant its own question!

Answer (score 2):

Because then you have that the dilation is a group homomorphism, i.e.
$$\delta_r (x*y)=\delta_r(x)*\delta_r(y)$$
And the 1-parameter property:
$$\delta_{rr'}(x)=\delta_r(\delta_{r'}(x)).$$
(Well, in fact this would hold with the usual scalar multiplication in $R^3$ as well.)

It also is compatible with the measure and Hausdorff dimension of the group.

As others answered correctly, there is good reason why one would have been able to guess/arrive at this formula.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in slightly different coordinates, the Heisenberg group is the collection of matrices $\pmatrix{1 & x & t \cr 0 & 1 & y \cr 0 & 0 & 1}$, with matrix multiplication, and the dilation is the conjugation by $\pmatrix{\lambda & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & \lambda^{-1}}$.

(The relation between these coordinates and the ones you gave amounts to using "exponential coordinates" for matrices, meaning to exponentiate the Lie algebra $\pmatrix{0 & x & t \cr 0 & 0 & y \cr 0 & 0 & 0}$, or similar.)